# LuaLaTeXで斜体フォント不在に就いて警告が出ない様にフォントを定義する方法

Tags: latex, font, lua

下記の例、エラーはありませんが、フォント関連警告が出ます：

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}

\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
]{HGS Gothic}


\begin{document}    
    \section{フォント試験試験}  
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 主要フォント
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 漢あア
                \item \bfseries{漢あア}
            \end{itemize}
        \item ゴシックのフォント
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \sffamily{漢あア}
                \item \sffamily{\bfseries{漢あア}}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

警告の内容は：

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 3745.

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc' does not contain script 'CJK'.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

`JT3/mc/m/it`にある`it`は斜体に参照するなら、日本語フォントには斜体が無い事は通常でしょう。日本語で入力する時には斜体を使わなくても構いませんが、この警告を正しい方法で表示されない様にしたいです。

`Font 'fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc'`も変ですが、この質問の話題以外になるでしょう・・・

Comment: 斜体が表示したいのではなく、警告が表示されなければ良いということでしょうか？

Comment: @packet0 コメント、感謝致します。そうです。警告が表示されなければ宜しいです、但し強制的警告消しはシステム開発上禁止の方法です。

Comment: こちらの環境で上の例だと`it`は使われなかったのですが、エラーがでた入力ファイルの3745行には別のものがないですか？警告の取り消しがダメだと、`it`を使わないようにするか、フォントを修正するしかないと思います。`sl`なら`AutoFakeSlant`でエラー出なくできますが…

Comment: @packet0, ご回答、有難う御座います。斜体フォントとしてどれのOSでも利用できる`AutoFakeSlant`を指定するなら、良いと思っております。恐れ入れますが、`\setmainjfont{}`の中に斜体が指定される例が見つけられなかったのですが、回答の所に一例を挙げて下さいませんでしょうか。